# JSTL c:forEach printing ${}

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I have a simple controller which has a method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products")
public ModelAndView showProducts(){
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("products");
mv.addObject("products", productDAO.getAllProducts());
return mv;
```

and then I have my products.jsp page with jstl included

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

Hello from products page.<br/>

<c:forEach var="prod" items="${products}">
    ${prod.price}
    ${prod.id}
</c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I see the result in the browser as ${prod.id} string and not the actual ID of the product I've set up. Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Comment: Your code appears to be off - in the second code block, there is a `<` outside of the code.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I assume that this was typo in question. Corrected.

Comment: yeah, that was a typo...the code is correct

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The problem was with the web.xml - I was using a default maven-webapp archetype and the web.xml had this

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

So I just removed it and JSTL started working.