# Display a Class ArrayList on JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist, getattribute

I am a beginner to Java.

What I am trying to achieve is take an input of Product code from JSP (index.jsp) webpage, call a servlet (getDetails) and get description and balance on hand for multiple location, from a DB2-I-series sedrver

In Servlet for description I am using Map, but to get balance of multiple location i am using a custom class ArrayList (displayOnHand).

Data is getting properly captured in servlet page for balance at multiple location, but when I do a setAttribute in Servlet and getAttribute in JSP for the same, I am not able extract data as 1 field at a time.

Can someone please help men.

Following is my code

```
-------- getDetails Servlet ------------------


public class getDetails extends HttpServlet {

  /**
   * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
   * methods.
   *
   * @param request servlet request
   * @param response servlet response
   * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
   * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
   */
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
      /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
      /* write your code here */

      Map < String, String > messages = new HashMap < String, String > ();
      ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
      displayOnHand data = new displayOnHand();
      ArrayList < displayOnHand > dataList = new ArrayList < displayOnHand > ();

      String scanSKU = request.getParameter("SKUScan");
      if (scanSKU == null || scanSKU.trim().isEmpty()) {
        messages.put("scanSKU", "Please Enter SKU/UPC/EAN Code");
      }

      if (messages.isEmpty()) {

        String driver = getServletContext().getInitParameter("driver");
        String connectionString = getServletContext().getInitParameter("connectionString");
        String username = getServletContext().getInitParameter("username");
        String password = getServletContext().getInitParameter("password");

        try {
          Class.forName(driver);
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password);
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String rsstmt = "select IDESCR from mm510lib.invmst where inumbr =" + scanSKU;
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(rsstmt);

          String SKUName = "";
          while (rs.next()) {
            SKUName = rs.getString(1);
          }
          //String SKUName = rs.getString(1);
          messages.put("SKUDescription", SKUName);
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          rsstmt = "select istore, IBHAND from mm510lib.invbal where inumbr =" + scanSKU;
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(rsstmt);

          ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
          int columns = md.getColumnCount();

          //  Get column names
          //for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
          //    columnNames.add(md.getColumnName(i));
          // }
          //  Get row data
          //while (rs.next()) {
          //    ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);
          //    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
          //        row.add(rs.getObject(i));
          //    }
          //    data.add(row);
          //}
          while (rs.next()) {
            //displayOnHand data = new displayOnHand();
            data.setLocationCode(rs.getInt(1));
            data.setOnhand(rs.getInt(2));
            dataList.add(data);
          }
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(getDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          messages.put("connection", "Connection to Database could not be established");
        }

        request.setAttribute("messages", messages);
        request.setAttribute("onHandClass", data);
        request.setAttribute("OnHandDetails", dataList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
      }
    }
  }


---------------------------------------------------- index.jsp ----------------------------------------------------


<%@page import="java.util.List" %>
  <%@page import="java.sql.Array" %>
    <%@page import="java.util.Locale.Category" %>
      <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
        <%@page import="JavaPackages.*" %>
          <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <title>Store MIS V0.1</title>
              <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

              <script type='text/javascript'>
                function isNumber(evt) {
                  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event; // for IE
                  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
                  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                }
              </script>
            </head>

            <body>
              <div class="hypLogo">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="pageHeader">
                  <h1>Store MIS</h1>
                  <form action="getDetails.do" method="POST">
                    <p>
                      <input type="text" name="SKUScan" value="" placeholder="Scan SKU" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
                    </p>

                    <span class="error">${messages.scanSKU}</span>
                    <p class="submit">
                      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Enter">
                    </p>
                    <span class="error">${messages.connection}</span>
                    <span class="error">${messages.SKUDescription}</span>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% out.println( "in Script"); if (request.getAttribute( "OnHandDetails") !=n ull) { // retrieve your list from the request, with casting ArrayList<displayOnHand>list = (ArrayList
                <displayOnHand>) request.getAttribute("OnHandDetails"); displayOnHand tempData = new displayOnHand() ; out.println("Array Size" + list.size()); // print the information about every category of the list for (int i = 0; i
                  < list.size(); i++) { tempData.equals(list.get(i));
                  } } %>
            </body>

            </html>

------------- displayOnHand Class ---------------

public class displayOnHand {

private int storeNumber;
private int onHandBal;

public displayOnHand() {

}

public void setLocationCode(int strNum) {
    storeNumber = strNum;
}

public int getLocationCode() {
    return storeNumber;
}

public void setOnhand(int onHand) {
    onHandBal = onHand;
}

public int getOnHand() {
    return onHandBal;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add instance of Product in the list e.g. 
`List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();`  and add the product as `productList.add(p);` where p is any instance of Product. For display use for loop e.g.

```
for(i=0;i<productList.size();i++) 
{ 
Product product = list.get(i); 
out.println(product.price); 
out.println(product.id);  
}
```

Comment: It was so simple at last, I tried whole lot of complicated ways to get this done. Thanks Once more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstl tag library to iterate over arraylist. For example, you can use `c:forEach` tag.

Comment: Thanks for revert, but I am not familiar with JSTL, would like something in JSP itself.

Comment: @KapilTulsan : JSTL is just the part that allows conditions and loops in JSP. You will not be able to do serious JSP without it. Of course you could use scriptlets instead of JSTL but please **do not even try** : it is error prone and gives hard to read JSPs.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta but as of now I would not try my hand on JSTL , if any scriplets code would help I would like to fix it as of now.

Comment: I really insist that you cannot seriously use JSP without JSTL. You have a simple usage example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29905584/3545273)

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta will try this sometime, but got some help from other forum member. Thanks Once more.

Comment: @KapilTulsan : Looks like I should have first asked where was the JSP :-)

Answer (score 0):

for iteration you can also use for loop 
e.g.

```
for(i=0;i<list.size();i++)
out.println(list.get(i));
```

OR

you can also use JSTL tags as @vivek mentioned

Comment: you can add instance of Product in the list e.g.

Answer (score 0):

You really should try to use JSTL.

It is as simple as (stolen from [JSTL c:forEach printing ${}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29905584/3545273)) :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

Hello from products page.<br/>

<c:forEach var="prod" items="${products}">
    ${prod.price}
    ${prod.id}
</c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
```

With a nice XML file.

If you really cannot use JSTL, it would be :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="package.to.Product"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

Hello from products page.<br/>
<%
    List<Product> products = (List<Product>) request.getAttribute("products");
    for (Product prod: products) {
        page.setAttribute("prod", prod);
%>
    ${prod.price}
    ${prod.id}
<% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

Pretty ugly isn't it (and I didn't even test it) ? Believe me : unless you really cannot do differently **avoid** scriptlets !